# How to handle missing values (NA's) in a column in lmer

Tags: r, na, lme4, mixed-models

I would like to use `na.pass` for `na.action` when working with `lmer`. There are `NA` values in some observations of the data set in some columns.  I just want to control for this variables that contains the `NA`'s. It is very important that the size of the data set will be the same after the control of the fixed effects.
I think I have to work with `na.action` in `lmer()`. I am using the following model:

```r
baseline_model_0 <- lmer(formula=log_life_time_income_child ~  nationality_dummy + 
    sex_dummy + region_dummy + political_position_dummy +(1|Family), data = baseline_df
```

> Error in qr.default(X, tol = tol, LAPACK = FALSE) :
> NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

My data: as you see below, there are quite a lot of NA's in all the control variables. So "throwing" away all of these observations is no option!

One example:

```
nat_dummy
1   : 335
2   :  19
NA's: 252
```

My questions:

1.) How can I include all of my control variables (expressed in multiple columns) to the model without kicking out observations (expressed in rows)?

2.) How does `lmer` handle the missing variables in all the columns?

Comment: If lmer does not handle missing values, you can use `Hmisc` to do missing value imputation. for example `hmisc::impute(baseline_df, median)` for impute with the median. There are a [Task View on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MissingData.html) for work with missing data that list available packages depending on your needs.

Comment: @RicVillalba: I wouldn't recommend single imputation except for the quickest/dirtiest of analyses (neither would Frank Harrell, the author of `Hmisc`; for any serious analysis the OP should be using multiple imputation, e.g. as implemented in `mice`. I would answer, but don't want to take this away from you. Might answer tomorrow.

Comment: It may benefit all parties if you provide a reproducible dataset to work with if possible. If you run `dput(baseline_df)` and paste the output into your question, people can provide a more direct answer to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your second question, `lmer` typically uses maximum likelihood, where it will estimate missing values of the dependent variable and kick out missing values of your predictors. To avoid this, as others have suggested, you can use multiple imputation instead. I demonstrate below an example with the `airquality` dataset native to R since you don't have your data included in your question. First, load the necessary libraries: `lmerTest` for fitting the regression, `mice` for imputation and `broom.mixed` for summarizing the results.

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(lmerTest)
library(mice)
library(broom.mixed)
```

We can inspect the missing patterns with the next code:

```
#### Missing Patterns ####
md.pattern(airquality)
```

Which gives us this nice plot of all the missing data patterns. For example, you may notice that we have two observations that are missing both `Ozone` and `Solar.R`.

[image]

To fill in the gap, we can impute the data with 5 imputations (the default, so you don't have to include the m=5 part, but I specify explicitly for your understanding.

```
#### Impute ####
imp <- mice(airquality,
            m=5)
```

After, you run your imputations with the model like below. The `with` argument takes your imputed data and runs each imputation with the regression model. This model is a bit erroneous and comes back singular, but I just use it because its the quickest dataset I could remember with missing values included.

```
#### Fit With Imputations ####
fit <- with(imp,
            lmer(Solar.R ~ Ozone + (1|Month)))
```

From there you can pool and summarize your results like so:

```
#### Pool and Summarise ####
pool <- pool(fit)
summary(pool)
```

Obviously with the model being singular this would be meaningless, but with a proper fit model, your summary should look something like this:

```
         term    estimate  std.error statistic       df     p.value
1 (Intercept) 151.9805678 12.1533295 12.505262 138.8303 0.000000000
2       Ozone   0.8051218  0.2190679  3.675216 135.4051 0.000341446
```

As Ben already mentioned, you need to also determine *why* your data is missing. If there are non-random reasons for their missingness, this would require some consideration, as this can bias your imputations/model. I really recommend the `mice` vignettes here as a gentle introduction to the topic:

https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/

#### Edit

You asked in the comments about adding in random effects estimates. I'm not sure why this isn't already something ported into the respective packages already, but the `mitml` package can help fill that gap. Here is the code:

```
#### Load Library and Get All Estimates ####
library(mitml)
testEstimates(as.mitml.result(fit),
              extra.pars = T)
```

Which gives you both fixed and random effects for imputed `lmer` objects:

```
Call:

testEstimates(model = as.mitml.result(fit), extra.pars = T)

Final parameter estimates and inferences obtained from 5 imputed data sets.

             Estimate Std.Error   t.value        df   P(>|t|)       RIV       FMI 
(Intercept)   146.575    14.528    10.089    68.161     0.000     0.320     0.264 
Ozone           0.921     0.254     3.630    90.569     0.000     0.266     0.227 

                           Estimate 
Intercept~~Intercept|Month  112.587 
Residual~~Residual         7274.260 
ICC|Month                     0.015 

Unadjusted hypothesis test as appropriate in larger samples.
```

And if you just want to pull the random effects, you can use `testEstimates(as.mitml.result(fit), extra.pars = T)$extra.pars` instead, which gives you just the random effects:

```
                               Estimate
Intercept~~Intercept|Month 1.125872e+02
Residual~~Residual         7.274260e+03
ICC|Month                  1.522285e-02
```

Comment: Thats a great explanation! THX!  One question left: It's clear now, how I can check the fixed effects's relevance with the imputations. But what happens with the random effect (1|Month) in the model? Becaus I want to find the influence from the fixed effects on the variance component of the random effect after controlling.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include that too.

Comment: You are a true master! thx a lot!

Comment: Haha no problem. If you felt this was helpful, please accept my answer by clicking on the arrow next to it.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no **easy** answer to your question; using `na.pass` doesn't do anything smart, it just lets the `NA` values go forward into the mixed-model machinery, where (as you have seen) they screw things up.

For most analysis types, in order to deal with missing values you need to use some form of *imputation* (using a model of some kind to fill in plausible values). If you only care about prediction without confidence intervals, you can use some simple *single imputation method* such as replacing `NA` values with means. If you want to do inference (compute p-values/confidence intervals), you need *multiple* imputation, i.e. generating multiple data sets with imputed values drawn differently in each one, fitting the model to each data set, then pooling estimates and confidence intervals appropriately across the fits.

`mice` is the standard/state-of-the-art R package for multiple imputation: there is an example of its use with `lmer` [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117605/lmer-with-multiply-imputed-data).

There a bunch of questions you should ask/understand the answers to before you embark on any kind of analysis with missing data:

- what kind of missingness do I have ("completely at random" [MCAR], "at random" [MAR], "not at random" [MNAR])? Can my missing-data strategy lead to bias if the data are missing not-at-random?
- have I explored the pattern of missingness? Are there subsets of rows/columns that I can drop without much loss of information (e.g. if some column(s) or row(s) have mostly missing information, imputation won't help very much)
- `mice` has a variety of imputation methods to choose from. It won't hurt to try out the default methods when you're getting started (as in @ShawnHemelstrand's answer), but before you go too far you should at least make sure you understand what methods `mice` is using on your data, and that the defaults make sense for your case.

I would strongly recommend the relevant chapter of Frank Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies*, if you can get ahold of a copy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll see if I can grab a copy myself.